# How do I change the output size of torch.nn.Linear while preserving existing parameters?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I am programming a PyTorch model which includes the following:

```py
self.basis_mat=torch.nn.Linear(
in_features=self.basis_mat_params[0],
out_features=self.basis_mat_params[1],
bias=self.basis_mat_params[2]).to(device)
```

Now what I want to do is to dynamically increment the `out_features` of `self.basis_mat`. However, I also want to preserve any previously trained parameters. In other words, we randomly initialize any new parameters while leaving the rest unchanged, while `out_features` is being incremented in the model.

So, what should I do?

I didn't really know what to try... I checked [the documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html), but it turns out that in `torch.nn.Linear` the parameter `out_features` is unchangeable and if I instantiate a new `torch.nn.Linear` (which would be quite slow I guess, so even if something similar works I would only use this as a last resort) the parameters are inbuilt, random, and unadjustable.

Comment: You can create a tensor which is a concatenation of trained parameters and random parameters and load that tensor into the weights and biases of linear layer. 
Please checkout this link [How to initialize weight with arbitrary tensor](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-initialize-weight-with-arbitrary-tensor/3432)

Comment: @tonygrey Thank you! Can you change your comment to an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following,

```
from torch import nn
import torch 
dim1 = 3
dim2 = 4 
dim3 = 5 
older_weight_parameters = torch.zeros( dim1, dim2) # replace this with older parameters, older_linear_layer.weight.t().detach()
older_bias_parameters = torch.zeros( dim2) # replace this with older parameters, older_linear_layer.bias.detach()

linear_layer = nn.Linear(dim1, dim2 + dim3)
# This will fill the corresponding parameters with the older parameter values
linear_layer.weight.data[:dim2, :] = older_weight_parameters.t()
linear_layer.bias.data[:dim2] = older_bias_parameters
```

Then the linear layer will have the following weight and bias parameter values. You can see the values of older parameters (in the examples these are zero values) have replaced the random parameters in the respective places.

```
linear_layer.weight, linear_layer.bias
(Parameter containing:
 tensor([[ 0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000],
         [ 0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000],
         [ 0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000],
         [ 0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000],
         [ 0.3455, -0.3385,  0.4746],
         [-0.2067, -0.4950, -0.3668],
         [-0.4012, -0.3951, -0.3772],
         [-0.1393,  0.3602, -0.0460],
         [-0.4641,  0.2152,  0.4031]], requires_grad=True),
 Parameter containing:
 tensor([ 0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0502, -0.3423,  0.3871, -0.5218,
         -0.4322], requires_grad=True)
```

The weights and bias parameters of the Linear layer are like any other tensor. You can use tensor manipulation on it.